# Upload file from react to webapi c#

Tags: c#, reactjs, webapi

I want to upload a image with some additional description, but I don't know how to process it further

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    var files = e.target.files[0]
    this.setState({imagesToDB: [...this.state.imagesToDB, files])
}
```

My react component

```
submitProperty = (e) => {
    const { title, location, address, rooms, beds, baths, typeProperty, price, description, imagesToDB } = this.state

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("title", title)
    form.append("location", location)
    form.append("address", address)
    form.append("rooms", rooms)
    form.append("beds", beds)
    form.append("baths", baths)
    form.append("typeProperty", typeProperty)
    form.append("price", price)
    form.append("description", description)
    form.append("Files", imagesToDB)


    e.preventDefault()
    fetch("api/advertentie/test", {
        method: "POST",
        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
        body: form
    })
```

Web api controller

```
public IHttpActionResult Post()
}
    var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
    // file says that it is empty. I see tutorials that I need to for loop
    // over the files but it is empty..

    var form = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
    // I receive the form with 10 parameters
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Files"];
    // the result of requests is "[object File]"
}
```

My question is: how can I save the `"[object file ]"` in my database?

Comment: Usually you need to foreach all the files from the request and then process each file individually (get FileName, ContentDisposition, etc...).

Comment: Yes, but the ```count = 0```, ```AllKeys``` gives me also 0. When I ```foreach``` over the request, I get chars like 91, 102 , 00